# Mule dataweave extract elements from json array

Tags: mule, dataweave

I have the following json and I'm trying to extract certain elements of the phones array. I don't always get 2 elements, it could be 1,2, or 3.

```
{
"phones": [{
        "id": 123,
        "phoneType": "H",
        "phoneNumber": "2125551212",
        "countryCode": "1",
        "isCellPhone": false,
        "optInTexting": false
    }, {
        "id": 456,
        "phoneType": "W",
        "phoneNumber": "9197776262",
        "countryCode": "1",
        "isCellPhone": true,
        "optInTexting": true
    }
]
```

}

This is what I have with the output:

```
%output application/java
---
{
   HOMEPH:  payload.phones filter ($.phoneType == "H") map {HOMEPH:.phoneNumber},
   WORKPH:  payload.phones filter ($.phoneType == "W") map {WORKPH:$.phoneNumber}
}
```

The results I get from this:

```
HOMEPH: [{HOMEPH=2125551212}]
WORKPH: [{WORKPH=9197776262}]
```

What I want:

```
HOMEPH: "2125551212",
WORKPH: "9197776262"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following ways

```
%output application/java
---
{
   HOMEPH:  (payload.phones filter ($.phoneType == "H") map ($.phoneNumber)) [0],
   WORKPH:  (payload.phones filter ($.phoneType == "W") map ($.phoneNumber)) [0]
}
```

Or

```
%output application/java
%var phoneLookup = {(payload.phones map { 
    ($.phoneType) : $
})}
---
{
   HOMEPH:  phoneLookup["H"].phoneNumber,
   WORKPH:  phoneLookup["W"].phoneNumber
}
```

Second option is more efficient as it iterates your payload once. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: yup that's what I was looking for. Since I filter to one element in the array and I want that single element [0], it pulls what I need. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using output as `application/java` , you can try following:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
{
    (payload.phones filter ($.phoneType == "H") map {HOMEPH:$.phoneNumber}),
    (payload.phones filter ($.phoneType == "W") map {WORKPH:$.phoneNumber})
}
```

You will get the output as below:
[image]

If you add Object to string transformer after Dataweave, you will get:

```
{HOMEPH=2125551212, WORKPH=9197776262}
```